# android -Menu function

Tags: android

I am new to android.I have tested the android.view.menu by the following code..It works.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
public class menu extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
    menu.add(Menu.NONE, 1, Menu.NONE, "1 Pixel");
    menu.add(Menu.NONE, 2, Menu.NONE, "2 Pixels");
    menu.add(Menu.NONE, 3, Menu.NONE, "8 Pixels");
    menu.add(Menu.NONE, 4, Menu.NONE, "16 Pixels");
    menu.add(Menu.NONE, 5, Menu.NONE, "24 Pixels");
    menu.add(Menu.NONE, 6, Menu.NONE, "32 Pixels");
    menu.add(Menu.NONE, 7, Menu.NONE, "40 Pixels");
    return(super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu));
    }
}
```

I just what to know how to add action to each menu.whether we can add intent to each menu buttons.if possible please help me out.Thanks in advance..

Comment: Sure you can add intent to your menu button clicks. As suggested by Rockon ... inside switch-case you can startActivity ( new Intent....)
before break.

Answer (score 0):

To create menu you need both of the methods without using xml:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
                super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
            this.menu = menu;

            menu.add(0, 1, Menu.NONE, "Save");

            menu.add(0, 2, Menu.NONE, "Close"); 

            return true;
         }



    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

            switch (item.getItemId()) {

            case 1:          
                  break;
                case 2:       
                  break;
            }
          return false;
     }
```